# issue with animating the radio button

Tags: html, css

I want to use radio buttons of this Codepen and I copy pasted some of the code but when I click each radio button a wired animation occurs despite I copied and paste the original css:

[This is the original codepen.](https://codepen.io/RoshitShrestha/pen/gOwojgw)

And this is my code:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}

.ab-form .ab-form-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.ab-form .ab-form-list__item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox,
.ab-form .ab-radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}

.ab-form .ab-radio {
  /* label end */
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.ab-form .ab-radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<form class="ab-form">
  <ul class="ab-form-list">
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="children">
        <label for="children">children</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="teen">
        <label for="teen">teen</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="adult">
        <label for="adult">adult</label>
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Comment: It's the border. If you click the radio button then only the border will be added. If you want to have an effect like in the codepen then you have to decrease the width and the height of the circle when you click on the radio button. And instead of copy paste, you can try to understand the code and maybe even make it better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Added `*, ::after, ::before {box-sizing: border-box;}`  for more info about [box-sizing](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}
*, ::after, ::before {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.ab-form .ab-form-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.ab-form .ab-form-list__item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox,
.ab-form .ab-radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
  transition: color 0.15s ease;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #dddd;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, box-shadow 0.2s ease, border 0.1s ease-in;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}

.ab-form .ab-radio {
  /* label end */
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}
.ab-form .ab-radio:checked + label::before {
  background: #ffffff;
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 7px;
  transition: background 0.2s ease, border 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

```html
<form class="ab-form">
  <ul class="ab-form-list">
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="children">
        <label for="children">children</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="teen">
        <label for="teen">teen</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="adult">
        <label for="adult">adult</label>
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Done!

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");

*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

.radio {
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: 500;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  color: #333;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.radio + .radio {
  margin-left: 20px;

}

.radio input[type="radio"]{
  display: none;

}

.radio span {
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 3px solid mediumblue;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 7px;
}

.radio span:after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  width: 8px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid mediumblue;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(0);
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: 300ms ease-out 0s;
}

.radio input[type="radio"]:checked ~ span:after {
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="radio-group">
      <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="children" name="deep">
          children
          <span></span>
      </label>

      <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Teen" name="deep">
          Teen
          <span></span>
      </label>

      <label class="radio">
          <input type="radio" value="Adult" name="deep">
          Adult
          <span></span>
      </label>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
    <form class="ab-form">
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="age" />
        children
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="age" />
        teen
      </label>
      <label>
        <input type="radio" name="age" />
        <span> adult </span>
      </label>
    </form>
```

```css
      @import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
      * {
        font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
      }
      form {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-left: 30px;
      }
      label {
        text-transform: capitalize;
        cursor: pointer;
      }
      input[type="radio"] {
        position: relative;
        /* opacity: 0; */
      }
      form input[type="radio"]:checked {
        background-color: red;
      }
      input[type="radio"]::before {
        content: "";
        border-radius: 50%;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        top: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        width: 16px;
        height: 16px;
        background-color: #ddd;
        transition: 0.3s;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        border: 0px solid #adb0ee;
      }
      input[type="radio"]:hover::before {
        background-color: #eee;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px 3px #adb0ee;
      }
      input[type="radio"]:checked::before {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px 0px #adb0ee, inset 0 0 0 4px #7579e7;
      }
      input[type="radio"]:hover:checked::before {
        background-color: white;
        box-shadow: 0 0 0px 3px #adb0ee, inset 0 0 0 4px #7579e7;
      }
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans:wght@400;600;700&display=swap");
* {
  font-family: "Nunito Sans", sans-serif;
}

.ab-form .ab-form-list {
  list-style: none;
}
.ab-form .ab-form-list__item:nth-of-type(n + 2) {
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox,
.ab-form .ab-radio {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  user-select: none;
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #212121;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  background: #dddd;
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label::before,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label::before {
  background: #f5f5f5;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(117, 121, 231, 0.4);
}
.ab-form .ab-checkbox:hover + label,
.ab-form .ab-radio:hover + label {
  color: black;
}

.ab-form .ab-radio {
  /* label end */
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label {
  padding-left: 32px;
}
.ab-form .ab-radio + label::before {
  width: 22px;
  height: 22px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #7579e7;
}

.ab-form .ab-radio:checked + label::before {
  border-color: #7579e7;
  border-width: 2px;
}
```

```html
<form class="ab-form">
  <ul class="ab-form-list">
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="children">
        <label for="children">children</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="teen">
        <label for="teen">teen</label>
     </li>
     <li class="ab-form-list__item">
        <input type="radio" name="age" class="ab-radio" id="adult">
        <label for="adult">adult</label>
     </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```